# Set a tabindex for an ASP.net RadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I'm having following asp RadioButton group, in an ASP.net form

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="col-sm-1 padding0">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="optMale" Checked="true" runat="server" GroupName="Gndr" TabIndex="110"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 labelText2">
        Male
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 padding0">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="optFemale" runat="server" GroupName="Gndr" TabIndex="111" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 labelText2">
        Female
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to go to every option of this asp radio button group once pressing Tab Key, currently it's going only for top selected radio button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you tab through all radio buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322564/can-you-tab-through-all-radio-buttons)

Comment: @Draken  HTML and asp.net behaviors different

Comment: What's the final code that ASP.net produces for the end user? HTML, it's HTML you are attempting to change the default pattern of, not ASP.net