# radio button checked and tabindex not working together

Tags: html, radio-button, checked, tabindex

As title says: its not working together

My Code:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio{{ tr.Id }}" value="y" tabindex="{{ tabindex }}">Correct
<input type="radio" name="radio{{ tr.Id }}" checked>Idk
<input type="radio" name="radio{{ tr.Id }}" value="n">Wrong
```

The tabindex is in this Code not working

when I remove `checked` `tabindex=""` is working

Im working with Twig and the Twig counter is correct ({{ tabindex}}) !!

Thanks in advance for every help :)

This Question might be a duplicate, but i just want to point out that checked and tabindex aren't working well together. Consider using a dropdown-menu as radio selection with `tabindex` and (in this case) `selected`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you tab through all radio buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322564/can-you-tab-through-all-radio-buttons)

Comment: `When focus moves to the group in which a radio button is selected, pressing Tab and Shift+Tab keys move focus to the radio button that is checked.`   This is said by the correct answer in your linked question. In my Example no radio box is focused: they get just ignored.

Comment: @Jannis Did you ever find a way around this issue? I'm having this same issue. Also using Twig and JS on the radio buttons. Tabbing is just ignoring the next set of radio buttons. Some sets of radio buttons are generated dynamically and those are being ignored as well.

Comment: @JasonGlisson if I remember right I switched radio buttons to a drop down, which is basicly working the same (but Tabindex was working). It's worth a try

Comment: @Jannis Ah ok. That's not really an option because of the javascript tool that this is integrated into to. I think it would end up being a massive lift to redo it as dropdowns unfortunately. The tab focus just completely disappears when I tab to dynamically created radio buttons. Pretty frustrating.