# Accessibility issue, tabs not working for custom inputs

Tags: html, input, tabs, accessibility

I'm having an issue where only the initial checked input buttons are accessible by tabs. The inputs are set to 0 for visibility, so it should work as far as I can tell. I also tried tab-index, but that did not do anything. What am I doing wrong?

[Here is the code in CodePen](https://codepen.io/jangeltun/pen/MWaZppV)

```css
.mainColorWrap input[type="radio"],
.imageSizeInputWrapOuter input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 position: relative;
 width: 0;
 margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}
.mainColorWrap label {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
.mainColorWrap label:hover,
.mainColorWrap label:focus,
.frontColorWrap label:hover,
.frontColorWrap label:focus {
 background-color: #000;
}
.mainColorWrap input[type="radio"]:focus + label {
 border: 1px solid #777;
}
.mainColorWrap input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: #777;
}
.radioButtonInner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainColorWrap">
   <form>
      <input type="radio" name="colorOption" id="redCheck" value="red" class="mainColorRadiogroup" checked="" tabindex="0">
      <label for="redCheck">
         <div class="radioButtonInner" style="background-color: #c10e21;"></div>
      </label>
      <input type="radio" name="colorOption" id="greenCheck" value="green" class="mainColorRadiogroup" tabindex="0">
      <label for="greenCheck">
         <div class="radioButtonInner" style="background-color: #0ec155;"></div>
      </label>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Radio button group considered as single item so when you press tab the focus moves to next element. Your code is working fine on arrow keys. Please read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322564/can-you-tab-through-all-radio-buttons

Comment: could you just add some more detail as to what you think isn't working, I agree with @ismi this all seems to function as expected as you have two inputs that are part of a radio group so you would change these with arrow keys. You could do with some focus indicators though that behave differently to the selected state as at the moment it isn't clear.