# Tabindex not working with the custom radio button

Tags: html, css, radio-button, tabindex

I have created a custom radio button. My issue with `tabindex`. When I press the tab then it's not selecting the radio button. I am getting the issue in the `Labelname1`.

How can I resolve this?

```js
$('input[name="tod-app"]').click(function() {
  if ($('#todNO').is(':checked')) {
    $('.is_hide').show();
  } else {
    $('.is_hide').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #2a2e3e;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:before {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
  border: 2px solid #5E1DD6;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:before,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:after,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #5E1DD6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.is_hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
      <label for="" class="form-label">City</label>
      <select name="city" class="form-select" tabindex="1">
        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Select city</option>
        <option value="">xyz</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group text-center position-relative todWrap">
      <label for="" class="form-label">Labelname1      
         </label>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center todWrapRadio">
        <div class="form-check  ps-0">
          <input type="radio" id="todYES" class="radio-custom" name="tod-app" value="1" tabindex="2">
          <label for="todYES" class="radio-custom-label">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" id="todNO" class="radio-custom" name="tod-app" value="0">
          <label for="todNO" class="radio-custom-label">No</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group is_hide">
      <label for="" class="form-label">This field is hidden and enable when choose NO from Lablename1 </label>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="form-check  ps-0">
          <input type="radio" id="lYES" class="radio-custom" name="limit" value="1">
          <label for="lYES" class="radio-custom-label">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" id="lno" class="radio-custom" name="limit" value="0">
          <label for="lno" class="radio-custom-label">No</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group position-relative">
      <label for="" class="form-label">Labelname2
         </label>
      <div class="d-flex" id="grossErrorshow">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-border-radiusR0 border-end-0" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="gross-1" tabindex="3">
        <div class="custom-dropdown">
          <select class="form-select input-border-radiusL0" aria-label="Default select example" name="roadunit" tabindex="4">
            <option value="mt">Sqr Mtr</option>
            <option value="sf">Sqr Fts</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group mb-4 position-relative">
      <label for="" class="form-label">Labelname3
         </label>
      <div class="d-flex" id="roadWideningErrorshow">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-border-radiusR0 border-end-0" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="road1" tabindex="5">
        <div class="custom-dropdown">
          <select class="form-select input-border-radiusL0" aria-label="Default select example" name="roadWidenUnit" tabindex="6">
            <option value="mt">Sqr Mtr</option>
            <option value="sf">Sqr Fts</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="" class="form-label">Labelname4</label>
      <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="width-access" tabindex="7">
        <option selected="" disabled="">Select access</option>
        <option value="0-9">
          < 9 Mtr</option>
            <option value="9-12">9 to 12 mt</option>
            <option value="12-15">12 to 15 mt</option>
            <option value="15-18">15 to 18 mt</option>
            <option value="18-24">18 to 24 mt</option>
            <option value="24-30">24 to 30 mt</option>
            <option value="30-0">> 30 mt</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group customrange position-relative">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label>Labelname5
            </label>
        <div class="loadinrangevalue"><input type="text" name="loading" value="0" max="100" tabindex="8">%</div>
      </div>
      <input type="range" class="form-range customRange" value="0" min="0" max="100">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span>0</span>
        <span>100</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xxl-12 col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" id="aggred" name="iaggred" value="1" tabindex="9"> I agree to the <a href="">terms and condition</a>
      <div class="iaggrederror"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pt-3 pb-3">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn themeBg btn-black" tabindex="10">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you are seeing the expected behavior as a group of radio buttons is basically one item which you can move through using arrow keys. Does this help? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322564/can-you-tab-through-all-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're positioning the "real" input out of the viewport using an absolute position. So, the tabindex input radio is actually working, but appling only to the "input", not the "label" tag.

I suggest setting tabindex to "label" tag instead of input:

```
<div class="form-check  ps-0">
  <input type="radio" id="todYES" class="radio-custom" name="tod-app" value="1">
  <label for="todYES" class="radio-custom-label" tabindex="2">Yes</label>
</div>
```

And adding custom CSS for input + label focused element:

```
[type="radio"]:focus + label {
    border-color: #86b7fe;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(13,110,253,.25);
    border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

If you want to select just de radio button:

```
[type="radio"]:focus + label:before {
    border-color: #86b7fe;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(13,110,253,.25);
    border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Is it possible to select the radio button?

Comment: Just updated, adding the CSS in the label:before pseudoelement will do the trick as it is where your radio button sytles are.

Comment: I tested but it's not selecting... can you please add the snippet?