# Tab selection ignores all elements generated within loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-group, tabindex

I have radio group in my application and this group builds based on array `const genders = ["Male", "Female", "Neutral"];`, when I press the `Tab` button focus falls at the first element only and goes further ignoring the rest of elements.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const genders = ["male", "female", "netural"];
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Hello Example</h1>
      <div>
        {genders.map((gender) => (
          <div key={gender}>
            <div>
              <input tabIndex={0} type="radio" value={gender} />
              {gender}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I have prepared working example and sahred it here: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-8j54h6?file=/index.js:62-436)

I have tried to add `tabIndex` to parent and to input element, but it didn't work.
When I add `tabIndex={0}` it selects parent element first and goes to the input element after clicking the Tab one more time, it is bad behaviour.

Please tell me how can it be fixed ?

Comment: Hi! I converted your code block into a **runnable** Stack Snippet using the `[<>]` toolbar button. [Here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/) for next time. On-site examples are much better than off-site ones. They help ensure your whole code is **in** your question, not just linked (yours was; thanks!); people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `name` to your inputs.

```
<input name={"gender-" + gender} type="radio" value={gender} />
```

Full example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const genders = ["male", "female", "netural"];
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Hello Example</h1>
      <div>
        <p>
          Same name (and same group, only 1 selected) - select first element with TAB and use arrows up and down
          keys to navigate
        </p>
        {genders.map((gender) => (
          <div key={gender}>
            <div>
              <input name={"gender"} type="radio" value={gender} />
              {gender}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <p>Different names (and group - you can select all of them) - use tab key to navigate</p>
        {genders.map((gender) => (
          <div key={gender}>
            <div>
              <input name={"gender" + gender} type="radio" value={gender} />
              {gender}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Notes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322638/5767872

> Radio buttons with one name is like single control (like input or select), you can change it value with arrow keys, tab key moves focus to another control.

(Thanks @t-j-crowder)

Comment: Then problem there is that by using different names, you've made them not part of a group. You can tick more than one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need kind of radio group behavior (only one selected from the set). You may add the same attr name for all inputs and that TAB will focus the first one. To navigate to the next you may use arrows key (actually navigate and select).

For example, check - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-radio-button/.

Answer (score 1):

There are really two problems:

1. Keyboard navigation isn't working as you expect.
2. The radio buttons don't form a *radio group*. Each of them is separate, and they can all be selected at the same time.

The keyboard navigation thing is largely a misunderstanding: You can't *tab* between the choices, because the set of elements is logically a single field (even though they're not acting like it right now). Instead, to use keyboard navigation, you tab to the group, and the select the options via the <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd> keys.

The issue with their not being a true group can be corrected by giving the radio buttons the same `name` (for instance, make them all `name="gender"`). Then they're mutually-exclusive, and they're properly in a group (which is important for assistive technologies).

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
    const genders = ["male", "female", "netural"];
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Hello Example</h1>
            <div>
                {genders.map((gender) => (
                    <div key={gender}>
                        <div>
                            <input name="gender" tabIndex={0} type="radio" value={gender} />
                            {gender}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

To further enable assistive technologies, ensure that each radio button is [*labelled*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
    const genders = ["male", "female", "neutral"];
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Hello Example</h1>
            <div>
                {genders.map((gender) => (
                    <div key={gender}>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                <input name="gender" tabIndex={0} type="radio" value={gender} />
                                {gender}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

You might also add a [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) around the group with a `legend`. (And put the whole thing in a `form`.)